# Drool: Is it possible to save decision table in database and exploit just like a excel rule file

Tags: spring-boot, drools

Hi I have created a rule set and saved in excel file.I was wondering if it will be possible to save the rules in database as in the same format as excel file and pull the rule from db and initialize the rules.

I have attached the rule file below.

[image]

Is there any way to save the rules in db in this format and get it out to work in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible. The question is: What are you gaining from it? You are adding more complexity by not relying on out of the box mechanics of Drools.

Anyway, here is how:

1. Store the excel sheet in database as binary blob, i.e.:

```
PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("update MyTable set binaryData = ? where id= 9");
st.setBinaryStream(1, new FileInputStream(xlsFile), (int)xlsFile.length());
st.execute();
```

2. Retrieve the file from database
3. Build KieBase dynamically:

```
    KieServices ks = KieServices.Factory.get();
    KieFileSystem kfs = ks.newKieFileSystem().write( "src/main/resources/myFile.xls", xlsByteArray );
    KieBuilder kieBuilder = ks.newKieBuilder( kfs );
    kieBuilder.buildAll();
    KieSession ksession = ks.newKieContainer(ks.getRepository().getDefaultReleaseId()).newKieSession();
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply Anton. But I was thinking rather than saving the raw file in db I want to save these contents in multiple tables. The rule name in one. The imports in one etc. and all the conditions maybe in another table. What I was thinking was If I could write a query then all the data will come to the result. Then build the rule in java. So if I has to change a condition I could simply change the condition let say value 10 to say 20 and rebuild the code and change rules. This could be more easy for non coding people. This was my whole thought.

Comment: Hi @pacman - you can do this by using Apache POI framework, this would allow you to read the XLS spreadsheet in java, extract the necessary information - such as column names, but also cell values  and store them in database into your desired table structure. But you would have to implement this custom solution on your own. I am not sure how is this easier though, for non coding people, than to change a spreadsheet value.

Comment: What if I want to save say in the given excel "huge" and "red" in database and change it in template whenever I want. Is that possible?